# Sorting a linked list issue

Tags: ruby, merge, linked-list

My code for sorting a linked list is below:

```
def sort_list(head)
    return head if head.nil? || head.next.nil?
    mid_node = find_mid(head) 
    second_half = mid_node.next
    mid_node.next = nil 
    left_half = sort_list(head)
    right_half = sort_list(second_half)

    merge(left_half, right_half)

end

def merge(left_head, right_head)

    left = left_head
    right = right_head
    dummy_head = dummy = ListNode.new(-1)


    until left.nil? || right.nil?
        if left.val > right.val
            dummy.next = right 
            right = right.next 
        else
            dummy.next = left 
            left = left.next
        end 
        dummy = dummy.next
    end

    #here there may be one list left over.
    dummy.next = left unless left.nil?
    dummy.next = right unless right.nil?

    dummy_head.next
end

def find_mid(head)
    return nil if head.nil?

    slow_ptr = fast_ptr = head 
    until fast_ptr.nil? || fast_ptr.next.nil?
        fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next
        slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next 
    end 

    slow_ptr
end
```

This is giving me a stack too deep error, and I'm not sure why. Seems like I'm terminating both functions appropriately. The sort_list logic looks fine to me, and I tested the find_mid function. Merge also looks fine to me...so what's off here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `find_mid` function. If you test it with a linked list of just two nodes, you would see it returns the last one instead of the first one.

Example:

```
list = ListNode.new(4, ListNode.new(3))
res = find_mid(list)
puts res.val # It would print 3
```

So, the list won't shrink any more and the code would repeat the recursion with a linked list of size 2 *forever*, or in reality, until the **stack too deep error**.

The solution then is to change the function as follows:

```
def find_mid(head)
    return nil if head.nil?

    slow_ptr = head
    fast_ptr = head.next
    until fast_ptr.nil? || fast_ptr.next.nil?
        fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next
        slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next
    end

    slow_ptr
end
```